# MediaElement doesn't play back after restored from TombStoning

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement that I use for playing a music across pages. Hence, I had to keep it as a resource in App.xaml.

Things works as expected until I press the Windows Button in my WP. The application gets tombstoned, and MediaElement stops playing as expected. On my Application_Deactivated, I explicitly call Player.Stop()

The issue happens when I restore the application. All the other state is restored, but the mediaelement doesn't play the music. I can see that the code responsible for music is getting hit, but MediaElement's MediaOpened is not fired. Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT [to clarify KeyboardP's question]

```
<Application.Resources>
    <MediaElement x:Name="ME" MediaEnded="RepeatMedia" Volume="1" AutoPlay="False" Height="0" Source="/Sounds/mywave.wav" />
</Application.Resources>
```

In my App.XAML.CS, I have a method called...

```
    public MediaElement player = null;

    private void InitializeMusic()
    {
        if (App.Current.Resources.Contains("ME"))
        {
            player = App.Current.Resources["ME"] as MediaElement;
        }
        player.MediaOpened += player_MediaOpened;
    }
```

I am initializing it again in...

```
    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeMusic();
    }
```

Comment: What event are you resuming the player from? The `MediaElement` has to be added to the Visual Tree before it can be played so you might be trying to play it before it's been added.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion keyboardP. Edited the question to clarify the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why but the `Source` attribute is removed after tombstoning, so try resetting the source in the code behind.

```
if (App.Current.Resources.Contains("ME"))
{
    player =(MediaElement) App.Current.Resources["ME"] as MediaElement;
    player.Source = new Uri("/Sounds/mywave.wav", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much keyboardP. It worked like a charm! I didn't even think of adding that Source thing back again!